# Can't pass env variables from GitHub Actions to Docker container

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I'm trying to pass variables in GitHub:

[image]

I have the following step in workflow:

```yaml
    - name: SSH into VPS and deploy
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.VPSHOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
        script: |
          export BLOG_POSTGRES_DB=${{ env.BLOG_POSTGRES_DB }}
          export BLOG_POSTGRES_USER=${{ env.BLOG_POSTGRES_USER }}
          export BLOG_POSTGRES_PASSWORD="${{ secrets.BLOG_POSTGRES_PASSWORD }}"
          export DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=${{ env.DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS }}
          export DJANGO_SECRET_KEY="${{ secrets.DJANGO_SECRET_KEY }}"
          cd /home/username/blog
          docker-compose -f prod.yml build
          docker-compose -f prod.yml up -d
```

In my `docker-compose`:

```yaml
  blog:
    ...... some settings
    environment:
      DB_NAME: ${BLOG_POSTGRES_DB}
      DB_USER: ${BLOG_POSTGRES_USER}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${BLOG_POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: blog_eng.config.settings.prod
      DB_HOST: some_host (set just for instance here)
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS: ${DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS}
      DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: ${DJANGO_SECRET_KEY}
```

The thing is that all variables which I set in "Secrets" tab and access through `secrets.SECRET_NAME` in my workflow, they are passed to Docker container. But "variables" are not.

I read doc (they tell that I will have access through `env`).
Then tried to use them directly `$VARIABLE`. But no luck, I still can't have access to them in container.

I need to have them passed to Docker container on server, like I have variables which I set in secrets.

What could possibly be wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: Variables from the "Variables" tab live in the `vars` context, they aren't automatically set in the environment.

Comment: _"I read doc (they tell that I will have access through `env`)."_ - which doc, because that's not correct. As mentioned above they're in the [`vars` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#vars-context), not the `env` context.

Comment: Also in the [Variables docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#using-the-vars-context-to-access-configuration-variable-values). Notice that the variables from that tab are referred to as "configuration variables" in the docs.

Comment: Thanks! You're right. Will take a look at the doc closely again.